# No Google BigQuery table created after importing data through webclient

Tags: csv, file-upload, google-bigquery, webui

I'm currently familiarizing myself with Google BigQuery by working through the examples at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/web-ui-quickstart. Doing a query over the pubic datasets runs fine.

I run into problems when uploading custom data into a new table through the WebUI. I create a new dataset and table, and upload the csv file provided with the example case. As in the example I input the schema and submit the file. Now the upload window stays on top and turns grey as if it's working. Nothing seems to happen afterwards though. When clicking away the upload window after a long wait, the table seems to be created in the tree on the left. However, when clicking on the table an error is shown:

*"Unable to find table: ndwtest-984:csvtest.csvdata"*

This seems like a trivial action, however I cannot seems to get it to work. I've tried varies different files, uploaded the file to Google Cloud Storage first and played around with the advanced options the last two days, but keep getting the same error.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some steps to help you:

- billing must be enabled
- you need to choose to upload one single TXT file from the example eg: yob2013.txt and not the zip file
- make sure the schema is entered as text: `name:string,gender:string,count:integer`
- on the last screen of the wizard you don't need to change the default CSV option parameters (for demo purposes works as it is)

I just tried the example, and it does work for me. In case you still have errors, than you can check your Job History menu in the Web UI, direct link would be, warning you need to put your Id in the link.

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/YOUR_ANONYMOUS_PROJECT_ID_HERE?pli=1